# Что значит знак "щит" в верхней панели в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Для чего он используется? И почему у меня его нет? После обновления Идеи импортирую настройки с предыдущей версии, может из-за этого? Если из-за этого, то как это обойти?
[image: IntelliJ IDEA]

У меня стоит IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4 Community.

Comment: А, что? А можно скриншот?)

Comment: @BigTows искал в интернете, не нашел. Поищу еще.

Comment: @BigTows добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае это запуск тестов с построением отчёта покрытия.

Покрытие тестами есть только в Ultimate версии.